# Prevent SQL injection

Tags: mysql, go, gorp

Question 1:

I have the below MySQL query which works fine but I've just discovered this is not a safe approach as its open to SQL injection. As you can see the where clause is an issue if I wanted to pass as an argument.

```
_, err := dbmap.Select(&response.AppsData, "SELECT...", ?)
```

Any advice much appriciated.

```
where := ""

for i := 0; i < (len(acl_user_apps)); i++ {
    fmt.Println(acl_user_apps[i].AppId)
    fmt.Println(acl_user_apps[i].Permissions)

    if where == "" {
        where = "WHERE Apps.id=" + strconv.Itoa(acl_user_apps[i].AppId)
    } else {
        where = where + " OR Apps.id=" + strconv.Itoa(acl_user_apps[i].AppId)
    }
}

query := "SELECT Apps.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategoryMatches.category_id,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as temp,   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategories.category_name,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as tmp_name FROM Apps LEFT JOIN AppCategoryMatches ON AppCategoryMatches.app_id=Apps.id LEFT JOIN AppCategories ON (AppCategoryMatches.`category_id` = AppCategories.id) " + where + " GROUP BY Apps.id ORDER BY " + sort_by + " " + order_by + " LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset)
_, err := dbmap.Select(&response.AppsData,query)
```

Question 2: Also just wondering if anyone has ever had issues passing ORDER argument...

```
_, err := dbmap.Select(&response.AppsData,
        "SELECT Apps.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategoryMatches.category_id,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as temp, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategories.category_name,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as tmp_name FROM Apps LEFT JOIN AppCategoryMatches ON AppCategoryMatches.app_id=Apps.id LEFT JOIN AppCategories ON (AppCategoryMatches.category_id = AppCategories.id) GROUP BY Apps.id ORDER BY ?", "title")
```

This ORDER is the simplest thing ever... why isnt it working?

Comment: One question per question. -1

Comment: What is the error with your `ORDER` query?

Comment: @elithrar please see below query samples in comments of second answer.

Answer (score 7):

You absolutely don't want to be "escaping" any strings on your own, nor concatenating strings to make queries.

1. Go's `database/sql` (http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package supports [parameterised queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by default - e.g. `db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? AND active=?", id, userStatus)` - where `?` acts as a placeholder for mySQL to handle your variables.
2. You can (in combination with parameterised queries) use a query builder like [mgutz/dat](https://github.com/mgutz/dat#use-builders-or-sql) that can help if you're not great at writing raw SQL. A package like that or [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) also helps pack/unpack queries to/from structs or maps in your application.

There's also a great guide [in this tutorial](http://go-database-sql.org/index.html) for using Go's database package. I highly suggest reading it.

Comment: I'd like to highlight that the parameter placehoder syntax is specific to the driver being used. For MySQL (as this question is tagged) it'd be `… id=? AND active=?` rather than `… id=$1 AND active=$2`. The [tutorial linked to in this answer has a small section about this](http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html#parameter-placeholder-syntax).

Comment: Good catch—corrected. Too used to Postgres placeholders!

Comment: Folks many thanks for your help... I rewritten query to use parameterised queries however unfortunately the error remains...

I am unable to ORDER BY using dynamic fields

Comment: **DOES NOT WORK::**

    `rows, err := db.Query("SELECT Apps.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategoryMatches.category_id,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as temp, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategories.category_name,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as tmp_name FROM Apps LEFT JOIN AppCategoryMatches ON AppCategoryMatches.app_id=Apps.id LEFT JOIN AppCategories ON (AppCategoryMatches.category_id = AppCategories.id) GROUP BY Apps.id ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT 1", "Apps.title")`

Comment: **BELOW WORKS:**
    `rows, err := db.Query("SELECT Apps.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategoryMatches.category_id,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as temp, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(AppCategories.category_name,'-1') SEPARATOR ',') as tmp_name FROM Apps LEFT JOIN AppCategoryMatches ON AppCategoryMatches.app_id=Apps.id LEFT JOIN AppCategories ON (AppCategoryMatches.category_id = AppCategories.id) GROUP BY Apps.id ORDER BY Apps.title DESC LIMIT 1")`

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Go language. But most of languages have function for escaping strings (PHP example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). If you're inserting only integers to your query, you only need to convert values from string to int.

Check this out: http://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/09.4.html maybe you'll find some answers.

And about your ORDER - can you put here complete sql query that you're calling?

Comment: Hello OndraTom,

there doesnt seem to be a escape string function for Go... not that I can find. Its actually a ORDER issue (not limit)

Comment: Check the article. There are tips how to prevent SQL injection in GO language :)

Comment: Note that escaping strings in PHP is also not the safe way to handle SQL queries. You should be using PHP's `mysqli` package where possible and writing parameterised queries.

Comment: You can write parameterised queries without mysqli package or PDO.

Comment: @OndraTom The `mysql` extension does not support bound parameters, so you cannot write them without `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @Jeremiah Winsley ok, I admit it. mysql library is depracated and you should use mysqli or PDO. But for example, you can combinate mysql_real_escape_string with sprintf and bound it in this way. I just wanted to help and hit the basic points :).

Comment: That's not what bound parameters are. That's just fancy string concatenation. Bound parameters are actually sent separately from the statement.